# Ajax callback after php executed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to display alert message with plugin sweetalert.
I have page that displays on index page 10 products
Each one has link(may be form with hidden fields) with data to send to php script

for example **script.php?id=x&b=x&c=z**

There is HTML with PHP

```
<?php foreach($datas as $data): ?>
<a href="auction_buy.php?id=<?php echo $data->$id; ?>&b=x&c=z" class="a">link</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

$datas is object with data from DB

Now if i add ajax

```
$('.a').click(function (event){ 
event.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href')
    ,success: function(response) {
       swal("Here's a message!"); 
       //Similar to alert(''); i tried alert too but it didnt work
    }
})
return false;
});
```

And alert('ok') or swal alert wont appear.
I have product decription page where code similar to this with form data works
so might it be problem with multiple links?

Code in product description that works

```
jQuery("#contactForm1").ready(function() {
var frm = $('#contactForm1');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           swal({  
                title: "Success!", 
                text: "Code worked",
                type: "success",
                confirmButtonColor: "#4B77BE", 
                confirmButtonText: "Ok",
                closeOnConfirm: true 
            },
                function() {
                    location.reload();
                }
            );

        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

});

What i need is to display the alert before or after the ajax function.
I really spent lot of time figuring this out, but im beginner in jquery, can anyone help me please? Thank you very much and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: The js parses new lines, so it is quite imperative that the "," before 'success' to be at the and of the url: bla bla line. If that doesn't fix it, check 1. if any errors are reported in js? (press f12 if u use firefox or chrome and reload the page and check the "all"/"errors" tabs), 2. if the request is sent, and what does it return (check the "net" tab).

Comment: ev.preventDefault(); will gets executed before ajax call, because of that you cannot get alert message

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.a').click(function (event){
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr('href')
   })
   .done(function(response) {
        swal("Here's a message!"); 
    )};
  //it should be here after ajax
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

You should declare the event.preventDefault() at the end. Also Keep in mind that success callback is  deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 you should use done().